# Delete empty pages from a 3D cell array with mixed data

Tags: matlab, 3d, cell-array

I have a 3D cell array with mixed data. Among them also empty cells. There are also mxn-arrays in the third dimension that have only empty cells. I want to remove those:

```
C(:,:,1) = {'A' 'B'; [] []; 'C' 'D'};     
C(:,:,2) = {[] []; [] []; [] []};
C(:,:,3) = {[] 1; 2 []; [] 3};

should become

C(:,:,1) = {'A' 'B'; [] []; 'C' 'D'}
C(:,:,2) = {[] 1; 2 []; [] 3}
```

so far I have this solution

```
C1 = C(:,find(~all(cellfun('isempty',C),1)));
old_m = size(C,1);
old_n = size(C1,2)/size(C,2);
reshape(C1,old_m,old_n,[]);
```

I mean it's basically only two lines of code. I just wonder if there's a more elegant or efficient method?

Thanks

Comment: The third dimension does not have the same number of columns as the other two and it generates an error.

Comment: My bad, I corrected that. Divakar got it anyway, I guess ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This -

```
C(:,:,~all(all(cellfun('isempty',C),1),2))
```

Or this -

```
C(:,:,any(any(~cellfun('isempty',C),1),2))
```